# Can I add Visualization to VLC

Tags: windows-7, music, vlc-media-player

Is there a way to add new [visualizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_visualization) to [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)?

The six included are OK but something new would be nice.

Comment: Why are you using VLC for music? It’s a terrific video player, but there are better audio players; like XMPlay.

Comment: @Synetech Why do you care? That's irrelevant to his question. And he's clearly not the only one, considering this post has ~25,000 views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No

There is no current way to get projectM to work inside of VLC as a visualization system. But, there is talk and desire from projectM of restoring that functionality. There was a period of time where projectM was unmaintained.

- https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=145735

You can see the maintainer of VLC saying in Jan 2019,

> I really want it back in VLC, notably if it is finally using openGL.

So hopefully sooner than later.

Answer (score 14):

... a solution for windows:

1) Browse to the VLC folder, e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC`, and create a new folder called `visualizations`

2) Download the latest [preset_samples](http://sourceforge.net/projects/projectm/files/presets-samples/) of [ProjectM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/projectm/), e.g. `presets-2.0.0-Source.tar.gz` and extract all the `.milk` files to the visualizations folder created above.

3) In VLC open Preferences from the menu, go to the *audio* tab and under Output select "Directx audio output" as your Output module. Also make sure that "LibprojectM effect" is selected as your Visualisation.

4) Still in the Preferences menu, click the "All" radiobutton at the bottom left corner. Go to *advanced preferences > Audio > Visualizations > projectM* and set the "projectM preset path" to `C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\visualizations`

4) Save your preferences, then activate the visualizations by going to the *audio menu > visualizations > and select projectM*

VLC will now begin using random visualizations from the preset folder you specified. With some tweaking, you can probably change the scripts to adjust how long each visualization plays for, etc. Enjoy!

*The above adapted from pyr0man99 at http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=32794&start=20*

Answer (score 6):

I've not used it myself, but you could look at [**ProjectM**](http://projectm.sourceforge.net/), which apparently works with VLC.

`ProjectM` is an open-source alternative to [MilkDrop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MilkDrop) and uses the same presets.  You can [find more presets at the Winamp forums](http://forums.winamp.com/forumdisplay.php?forumid=81).

(I use the Winamp AVS presets with Foobar2000 on my Windows HTPC)

Comment: One of the six items in my visualization menu are ProjectM.

Comment: @Nifle: Ah okay.  Well it looks like you should be able to use Milkdrop presets with that.  You may be able to find new ones in the forum at the link in my answer.

Comment: *Milkdrop presets* **??** If you have any information on how to access that from within VLC please update your answer (I don't like to have useful information in the comments) (please ping me with another @Nifle if you do)

Comment: @Nifle: This forum seems to be a good starting point for looking for new presets: http://forums.winamp.com/forumdisplay.php?forumid=81  I don't even know what OS you are using to give you detailed instructions.  Just search your system for the location of `*.milk` files, and add your new ones.  I use AVS presets myself, so I can't really help any further.

Comment: Good point with the OS, adding correct tag.

Comment: Sadly no `*.milk`files turned up on my `C:` so I don't know where to put them. But several forum post's suggests that it's in the pipeline for vlc so a +1 for pointing me on that direction (and for bothering to investigate)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enable visualizations in your VLC media player then this article might help: [Enable visualizations in vlc media player](http://www.thehelptimes.com/visualizations-in-vlc-media-player/)

Comment: Hello and welcome to superuser.com. Please do not just paste links to solutions, but take the time to describe the solution in your answer. The reason for this is that in the case that your link dies, then the solution will still be available on superuser.com.

Answer (score 1):

Download the milk files from project M, and in windows, paste them to a directory and in VLC, settings - point to your folder.

Comment: Can you at least add the download link?